# Cannot create a collection after deleting a previous collection with the same name on Firebase

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

After deleting a collection, I cannot create a collection with the same name again. I get no error, but the collection simply is not created. I get errors later in the code, when I try to access the collection, that has not been created.

Logging in and out after deleting the collection solves the problem, but I think there should be another way.

So, I create a new collecion on Firebase:

```
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("Collection1")
            .doc(documentToWriteTo)
            .set(mapToWrite);
```

Now I delete this collection (by deleting all documents inside this collection):

```
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("Collection1")
          .snapshots()
          .forEach((querySnapshot) {
        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot docSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
          docSnapshot.reference.delete();
        }
      });
```

Now, I would like to create a collection with the same name as the previous one again:

```
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("Collection1")
            .doc(documentToWriteTo)
            .set(mapToWrite);
```

There is no error returned and everything seems to have worked. But on the Firebase Console there is no document created and all later calls to this document fail.

If I create another document, e.g. "Collection2", then this works fine (until I delete it).

If I log out and log in again, after deleting a document, I can create the document with the same name ("Collection1") without any problems. Also, if I hot restart the app, it works without logging out and in again.

I feel like I would need a function to refresh the data on Firebase. Am I missing something?

Edit:
I tried to add the await for the delete function but it did not help. What I find really strange is that:

```
    try {
            await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection(addressedCollection)
                .doc(documentToWriteTo)
                .set(mapToWrite);
            print(
                "firebase_actions.dart writeMapToFirebase, map to write: $mapToWrite, target layer: $targetLayer, collection: $addressedCollection - successful");
          } on Exception catch (error) {
            print(error);
            print(
                "error in firebase_actions.dart writeMapToFirebase set, map to write: $mapToWrite");
          }
```

prints "successful". Even though no entry on firebase is created.

Comment: [You should not *force* a tag into your title.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem recreating a collection that I just deleted:

```
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('75958420');

await collection.add({ "message": "Hello world", "createdAt": FieldValue.serverTimestamp() });

var snapshot = await collection.get();
for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {
  await doc.reference.delete();
};

await collection.add({ "message": "Hello again", "createdAt": FieldValue.serverTimestamp() });
```

The biggest difference is that I `await` for the `delete()` operation to complete. You might want to give that a try in your code too.

Sandbox: https://zapp.run/edit/firestore-re-create-collection-zogu06zoogv0

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried adding "await" for the delete() function but it did not help. How can it be that writing to Firebase returns no error, but also no entry is created? In my application, there is much more code and I just don´t know where to look.

Comment: I recommend trying to reproduce it in isolation, just like I did above. Without a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is unlikely we'll be able to help much further.

Comment: I adjusted the code in your example, but now it tells me that I have insufficient permissions on Firebase. Would you please update the permissions? I am using FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("Collection1")
            .doc("test")
            .set({"testMessage": "Hello World"});

Comment: I'm not going to update my project's security rules for your minimal repro. Instead, I recommend you create your own project for that and use it in the fork.